# I'm trying to use the googlemap activity from Android Studio , but the google map doesn't show map when run the app

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

However, I tried with my friend's macbook, which is the same model I have and tried so many times, and it works and shows the google map once typed in the API key. I tried same project with exactly same code, but it only shows a blank page with google logo on the bottom of the screen.

I have tried paste the API key to the meta-data to replace YOUR_API_KEY. Did not work, and gives blank page.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

Then I tried put my API key to local.properties like this('My api key' was replaced with my key):

```
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=My api key
```

Then keep the AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

It still shows the blank page.

I tried all of above on my friends macbook and it works perfectly and shows the google map but it just doesn't work on my macbook. I'm not sure if it is the configeration problem or anything else.

Can someone help me with this?

The blank screen with google map logo are attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRuCP.png)

My purpose is to have the android studio also work on my machine. It would be really helpful. Many thanks, tech pros.

MapsActivity.kt as below:

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
```

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

 binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 setContentView(binding.root)

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}
```

}

Comment: add in your Gradle file.     // maps
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-utils-ktx:3.4.0'

Comment: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
this should be in your fragment container

Comment: @AyazMuhammad Thanks for the help, but it still shows blank page after I added the    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-utils-ktx:3.4.0'.   And the android:name..... is already in my fragment container.   Might other factors caused the problem?

Comment: do you add this in your class path   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

Comment: you are trying to emulator do you run on your mobile device also add access fine and CoarseFineLocation permission

Comment: @AyazMuhammad which file would that be?

Comment: @AyazMuhammad  I'm runing on an emulator

Comment: you should try to run on device i hope your map will load

Comment: classpath will add in your project level Gradle file

Comment: that should be like that.      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }

Comment: ye it has all that, the thing is, I tried it on my friend's machine, the same model I have, same code runs on his machine but mine just not showing the map. I really dk why